# SoundCloud javascript api bug if iframe deleted

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm using soundcloud widget html5: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget and i've a problem:

Users can play soundcloud sounds on my page. When they click play i create a soundcloud widget with javascript. All is correct. But the dom of my page is often modified by javascript and when a soundcloud iframe is deleted soundcloud javascript api will bug: all future widget creation will fail on this part of code (because previous iframe is missing):

```
_player = SC.Widget(document.getElementById(_iframe_id));
```

firebug trace:

```
TypeError: e.contentDocument is null
```

Do you know a way to fix/bypass this ?
Thank's !

Exemple code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/adixoq/1/edit . For use it:

1. Press button 1: Create a widget; when ready an alert message.
2. Press button 2: Create second widget; when ready an alert message.
3. Press button 3: Delete dom of iframe1, create third widget. The bug
   appear and ready event is not throwed

Comment: I would endeavor to make sure my other JavaScript didn't delete that sound cloud iframe.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code that is responsible for [re]creating the widget? Could you reproduce the bug on http://jsbin.com ? Thanks!

Comment: i will do it ;) (my code is big, i can't just paste it here, i edit the post when it's done)

Comment: post edited (jsbin.com was unavailable, i've post the code)

Comment: jsbin.com available now, i moved the code.

Comment: thanks, we are looking into it

Comment: news about the "bug" ? ;)

Comment: It lokk like fixed, soundcloud js has been fixed ?

Comment: the bug has been fixed, the answer with the update was removed for some reason

Comment: Nice, my test script work, thx !